# Semaphore not locking the process and instead proceeding and executing critical section

Tags: c, semaphore, race-condition, critical-section

I have 2+processes where both where the processes write logs of the processes into a file. To maintain syncrhonization I planned to used semaphores to make the process till when one guy is executing in the critical section. Below are the code snippets of the functions I used.

```
static int createAndInitializeSemphore()
{
       int                        rv                                = SUCCESS;
       FILE*                fptr                       = NULL;
#ifdef DEBUG
       char          szDbgMsg[256] = "";
#endif

       printf( "%s: --- enter ---", __FUNCTION__);


       while(1)
       {
              if(doesFileExist(MESSAGE_KEY_FILE) != SUCCESS)
              {
                     printf(  "%s: %s File doesnt exist Creating It", __FUNCTION__, MESSAGE_KEY_FILE);


                     fptr = fopen(MESSAGE_KEY_FILE, "w");
                     if(fptr == NULL )
                     {
                           printf(  "%s: Could Not Open the File", __FUNCTION__);


                           return FAILURE;
                     }

                     fprintf(fptr, "SCA APP LOG APP\n");
                     fclose(fptr);
              }

              if( (semKey = ftok(MESSAGE_KEY_FILE, 'B')) == -1 )
              {
                     printf( "%s: FAILED to generate Semaphore key", __FUNCTION__);

                     printf( "%s: Something went wrong ftok(): %s, errno=%d", __FUNCTION__, strerror(errno), errno);

                     rv = FAILURE;
                     break;
              }

              printf( "%s: Semaphore key[%d]", __FUNCTION__, semKey);


              semID = semget(semKey, 0, 0);

              if(semID == -1)
              {
                     printf( "%s: semget returned Error: %s, errno=%d", __FUNCTION__, strerror(errno), errno);


                     if ((semID = semget(semKey, 1, IPC_CREAT | 0666)) != -1)
                     {
                           printf( "%s: Semaphore ID Created", __FUNCTION__);


                           arg.val = 1;

                           if(semctl(semID, 0, SETVAL, arg) == -1)
                           {
                                  printf( "%s: semctl returned Error: %s, errno=%d", __FUNCTION__, strerror(errno), errno);

                                  //What to do now?
                           }
                     }
                     else if(errno == EEXIST)
                     {
                           printf( "%s: semID already exists", __FUNCTION__);

                     }
              }

              printf( "%s: Successfully Created Application Log Message Queue",__FUNCTION__);

              break;
       }

       printf( "%s: Returning[%d]", __FUNCTION__, rv);


       return rv;
}

static void lockSemaphore()
{
#ifdef DEBUG
       char   szDbgMsg[128] = "";
#endif

       struct sembuf sbuf;

       sbuf.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;
       sbuf.sem_num = 0;
       sbuf.sem_op = -1;

       if(semop(semID, &sbuf, 1) == -1)
       {
              printf( "%s: Failed to Lock Semaphore Id[%d]: %s, errno=%d", __FUNCTION__, semID, strerror(errno), errno);

       }

       return;
}

static void unlockSemaphore()
{
#ifdef DEBUG
       char   szDbgMsg[128] = "";
#endif

       struct sembuf sbuf ;

       sbuf.sem_flg = 0;
       sbuf.sem_num = 0;
       sbuf.sem_op = 1;

       if(semop(semID, &sbuf, 1) == -1)
       {
              printf( "%s: Failed to Un-Lock Semaphore Id[%d]: %s, errno=%d", __FUNCTION__, semID, strerror(errno), errno);

       }

       return;
}
```

createAndInitializeSemaphore will be called each process only once at the startup. Suppose if we have two processes P1 and P2, both writes logs into a file called log.txt.Below is the code how it looks like for both processes while writing logs into the file:

```
lockSemaphore();

/* code for opening the log file writing the logs and the close the file*/

unlockSemaphore();
```

But it is not working as expected. Even when P1 acquired the lock and executing the critical section P2 is also able to acquire the and executing in the critical section and file is getting corrupted. Could you please help where I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Good ol' SysV semaphores .. you might want to take a look at [`semaphore.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/semaphore.h.html) to make this a little simpler .. however, if [`semget`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/semget.html) fails, _then_ you try to get it again (`if(semID == -1) {...if ((semID = semget...`) .. is that your intent?

Comment: Any reason you're not using a mutex instead?

Comment: @txtechhelp It is not failing for me in semget. Both processes are executing critical section. I want to know where was I going wrong.

Comment: @dbush I thought it is better to use semaphores when it is across processes. Did not try with mutex. I always used mutexes for threads. Even if I use mutex and it fixes my code I still want to know why this semaphore thing is not working the way I wanted. Do you have some info on how to use mutexes for processes ? Is it same as threads ?

Comment: Actually, I didn't initially catch the multiple process part.  Haven't tried using mutexes that way before.

Comment: I'm more familiar with POSIX semaphores, but based on the [docs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/semget.2.html) and the code you've posted it's unclear where the issue might reside; chances are in how the IPC is being initialized elsewhere in your code. To that, if you're just trying to lock a file, why not use [flock](https://linux.die.net/man/2/flock)?